# Language from my parents

Tags: meaning, phrase-request, regional

My parents and grandparents used to say something like "Pippi Agire" which supposedly meant "Hurry up." I cannot find a reference to it anywhere. Does the word (or such combination of words) exist? Or is it made up? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Phil!

Comment: Doesn't ring any bells with me. It may help if you tell us where your grandparents were from.

Comment: Might it be *Per piacere*, which literally is “Please”, but possibly used as an invitation to do something?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. To me it sounded like '"Pippiagire." I know agire basically means "act", but in this form, I have no clue. Any help is appreciated, I think the area they were from was around Monte Cassino if that helps.

Comment: I've some ideas.. but before I answer with a wrong guess, can you please tell me from which region are your parents from?

Comment: They were from Monte Cassino area. I'm not exactly sure where. The reason I ask is because I heard it on an old tv show that was taking place in Italy, and one of the Village elders used it in a long Tirade, and I recalled my parents and grandparents using it. It was not just me they said it to. It was anytime they wanted us, (or anyone) to hurry up.

Comment: I agree with @DaG: it's “per piacere” in a Southern accent.

Comment: You can find the expression "pi piaciri" in a lot of books by Andrea Camilleri which corresponds to "per piacere" in standard Italian, that is, "please". See https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_siciliana.

Comment: @DaG: Could anyone write the correct answer, "pi piaciri"? (I'm using Camilleri's orthography).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite likely to be a local pronunciation of *per piacere*, which literally means “please”, but may be used to exhort one to do something.

As Charo remarks, the not-too-different Sicilian version *pi piaciri* is often found in Andrea Camilleri's books.

Comment: Thank you DaG I agree this seems to be it. it certainly sounds like it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I can make some guess:

1. Pippi is the nick from your name (your name is probably Philippe - - > Filippo in Italian - - > "Pippo"  is the nick for Filippo)
2. "Agire" means "act"... if you didn't speak Italian at that time,  it could be they were using an Italian term (I. e." agire") that in their opinion you would understand

they were basically saying "Phil, hurry up".

I'm not really sure about "agire". It sounds like a dialect term I can't really get the meaning of.  However I'm pretty sure that it's general meaning was "hurry up" or "let's go".

Comment: I've never heard *Agire!* used this way, but it's common to hear *Muoversi!*, also *Marsch!* (read marsh) can be used this way.

Comment: @Formagella in some dialects from the south there are words or idioms that have really strange sounds e. g.  https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetto_apulo-barese. The same applies for dialects from the north or from the islands. Maybe if we have more infos about Philippe family ''s origins then we can have a better guess.

Comment: Monte Cassino area. They would use it in talking to everyone, not just me. An example (again I'm not sure of the pronunciation) would be: "OK kids, let's go", then it would be followed by: "Pippiagire!  (Again, my best guess)

Comment: According to @DaG's excellent hypothesis that would be "OK kids, let's go - please!"

Comment: Thank you Walter, I must agree  with @DaG also. that seems to be the closest, and when I repeat it, it sounds pretty much like what they were saying to us. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You can find the expression "pi piaciri" in a lot of books by Andrea Camilleri which corresponds to "per piacere" in standard Italian, that is, "please". See https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_siciliana.

Comment: Guys great! In the end we have the answer!